# Pass object Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing

What is the difference between following code in Java? I couldn't clearly catch out how objects are passed in Java. Can anyone explain the code below.

```
package cc;

public class C {

    public static class Value {
        private String value;

        public void setValue(String str) {
            value=str;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }



    public static void test(Value str) {
        str.setValue("test");
    }

    public static void test2(Value str) {
        str=new Value();
        str.setValue("test2");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String m="main";
        Value v=new Value();
        v.setValue(m);
        System.out.println(v.getValue()); // prints main fine
        test(v);
        System.out.println(v.getValue()); // prints 'test' fine
        test2(v);
        System.out.println(v.getValue()); // prints 'test' again after assigning to test2 in function why?
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is *pass-by-value*. You passed the value of a reference to `v` from `main` into `test2` via the parameter `str`, which was lost when `str` was assigned to a new reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `test2()` a new instance is created and you are setting value in newer instance, and not in the Object whose reference is passed

```
public static void test2(Value str) {
        str=new Value();
        str.setValue("test2");
}
```

**See Also**

- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Its ok. But shouldn't the passed reference should point to new object created inside test2()? It is still pointing to old object even we changed inside the function. That is the thing I couldn't get it clearly?

Comment: No only value of reference are copied to new reference variable, So still v from main points to the object created in main, v (reference) its value is copied over to str and then new value is assigned to it when you create `new Value()`

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `v` into `test2` what you are actually doing is passing a *copy* of the reference that points to `v` into the method - think of it as a new variable which has the same value as `v`.

When you assign a new `Value` object to `str` inside `test2` you are assigning a new value to the copy of the reference - your original reference, which exists inside `main` is unaffected by this reassignment, and still refers to the original object.

When you execute your third `println` in `main` you are still using the original `Value` object, not the new one that was created inside `test2`, and so you see `test` and not `test2` printed out.

Answer (score 0):

in java, object is passed by value. it copies the reference of v2 to str.
Although you create a new object and assigned to str, str is local variable within test2 method scope. Only str inside test2 method is changed.

```
public static void test2(Value str) {
  str=new Value();
  str.setValue("test2");
  System.out.println(str.getValue());
}
```